# Retrieving unique id and input values from datatable in Shiny

Tags: shiny, dt

I am attempting to use DT in R to create a table for user review with an appended column (new_column) including a selectInput drop-down that allows them to designate the event as either keep or delete. I am stuck on how to retrieve both the unique id and the user input from the datatable to be able to apply the change to a separate dataframe in Shiny. I would like for the user to push a button ('submit') for the app to know when to capture the values -- with this am I able to circumvent rerending the table or is that a necessary part of capturing the value?

I have worked with Shiny quite a bit but am not super familiar with javascript or datatables in general so have been stuck on this for some time and would appreciate any pointers.

Here is a simplified version of my data and code:

[image: example data here]

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(

                  DTOutput('myTableOutput'),

                     br(),
                     
                  actionButton("submit", "Apply Changes"))



server <- function(input, output, session) {
            for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
              df$new_column[i] <- as.character(selectInput(inputId = df$unique_id[i], label=NULL, choices = c('keep'=TRUE, 'delete'=FALSE)))
            }

          output$myTableOutput <- DT::renderDataTable({
            datatable(
              df, 
              escape = FALSE,
              filter = "none", 
              editable = 'new_column',
              selection = "none",
              options = list(
                dom = "t",
                initComplete = JS(
                  "function(settings, json) {",
                  "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': 'DimGray', 'color': 'white'});",
                  "}"),
                drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '))
            )
          }, server = FALSE)

          observeEvent(input$submit,{
          #need to retrieve changes (preferably in a df) so I can apply them to another dataframe

          reviewed_table <- as.data.frame(input$mytable_cell_edit)

            
          })

}
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with rows with keep/delete?

Comment: hi @det! I would like users to be able to review the table, select keep/delete, then hit the submit button so the app can retrieve the values and either 1 or 0 can be marked for that entry in another table with a corresponding unique_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add reactive value (`lgl_vec`) that has values of all selectInput's inside your table:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  df[["new_column"]] <- map_chr(
    map(
      df[["unique_id"]],
      selectInput,
      label = NULL,
      choices = c(keep = TRUE, delete = FALSE)
    ),
    as.character
  )
  
  output$myTableOutput <- DT::renderDataTable({
    
      datatable(
        df, 
        escape = FALSE,
        filter = "none", 
        selection = "none",
        options = list(
          dom = "t",
          preDrawCallback =JS(
            'function(){Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());}'
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            'function(){Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());}'
          )
        )
      )
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    lgl_vec <- as.logical(map_chr(df[["unique_id"]], ~input[[.x]]))
    rv$reviewed_table <- df[lgl_vec, -ncol(df), drop = FALSE]
    print(rv$reviewed_table)
  })
}
```

Comment: hi @det- this is great, thanks so much! one follow-up question, I just tested this out and the unique_id isn't returned alongside the true/false input in the rv, any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: You could do `df[rv$lgl_vec, "unique_id"]`

Comment: @LunaDeloge I've done what you've asked for, if you want to retrieve filtered data.frame then you could do like I've told you. I've made edits for data.frame subset.